Having trouble connecting hibernate to Oracle database 21g
I am new to hibernate. I am trying to connect to Oracle using hibernate. Is there no hibernate dialect for Oracle 21? I have Oracle 21c installed.
Here's how my cfg file looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">singwithme20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

I am getting errors in console as follows:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to:
Error calling Driver.connect() [ORA-17067: Invalid Oracle URL specified
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17067/]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver.connect() [ORA-17067: Invalid Oracle URL specified
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17067/]

What could I be doing wrong? Please correct me on that.
I tried using different versions for jdbc driver in pom file.

The error says you have

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver.connect() [ORA-17067: Invalid Oracle URL specified

Your URL should look more like: jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1521/xepdb1

This blog may also help: https://rashm1n.medium.com/hibernate-orm-with-oracle-23c-free-7b21c9c9319f

Hi Norman, your suggestion really helped. I was able to run the app without any issues. Thanks for your help.

Awesome, if you could mark my answer as the answer, that'd be cool! thank you
